# Print statement inside function used within lambda function not executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, anonymous-function

In the code below, `gen_window` has a print statement in it but when I run the code the print statement doesn't get executed. Why is that and then how should I go about debugging such lambda functions? (Even the debugger ignores the breakpoint in these functions.)

```
getpairs = rdd.flatMap(lambda xi: gen_window(xi, n))


def gen_window(xi, n):
    x, i = xi
    l = []
    for offset in range(n):
        print("-->", (i - offset, (i, x)))
        l.append((i - offset, (i, x)))
    return l
```

Comment: where do you set n?

Comment: @vs97 This isa part of larger code. I just hard code n as 3 for testing. Would you like me to post more code? I unfortunately can't post all of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works:

```
def gen_window(xi, n):
    x, i = xi
    l = []
    for offset in range(n):
        print("-->", (i - offset, (i, x)))
        l.append((i - offset, (i, x)))
    return l

xi = [3,5]
n = 3

gen_window(xi, n)
```

Lambdas only get executed wenn you actually use them - If you get no output you are probably never using it.

Output:

```
--> (5, (5, 3))
--> (4, (5, 3))
--> (3, (5, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions always return an iterator hence you would have to wrap that lambda call into a list

## Define a function that returns the length of a string

def string_length(s):
length = len(s)
print(f"The length of '{s}' is {length}")
return length

## Define a list of strings

strings = ["hello", "world", "python"]

## Apply the function to each element in the list using map and a lambda function,

## then convert the result to a list

lengths = list(map(lambda x: string_length(x), strings))

## Print the resulting list of lengths

print(lengths)
This would execute the print  statements

## Define a function that returns the length of a string

def string_length(s):
length = len(s)
print(f"The length of '{s}' is {length}")
return length

## Define a list of strings

strings = ["hello", "world", "python"]

## Apply the function to each element in the list using map and a lambda function,

## then convert the result to a list

lengths = map(lambda x: string_length(x), strings)

## Print the resulting list of lengths

print(lengths)

But this would not

Comment: please format it.